# Как сохранить новый лист в .xls файле через цикл?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, циклы, обработка-данных

Имею следующий запрос:

```
ids = ['766', '976']

for id in ids:
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Statistics.xls', engine='xlsxwriter')
    submit_ = pd.read_sql(con=connection, sql=sql, params={'id': '%{}%'.format(id)})
    parse = parse_reslt(submit_)
    parse.to_excel(writer, id, index=False)
    writer.save()
    writer.close()
```

Пытаюсь перебрать массив `ids` и получившийся результат сохранить в .xls файле, где результат запроса будет на отдельном листе в файле. Но сохраняется только один лист.

Подскажите, что делаю не так в данном случае?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В официальной документации по [pd.ExcelWriter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) показан пример того как создавать Excel файл c несколькими листами.

В вашем случае можно сделать так:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("Statistics.xlsx") as writer:
    for id in ids:
        ...
        parse.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=id, index=False)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, спасибо за дельное замечание - я дополнил ответ)